# What is systemd "refresh-policy-routes" [AWS Linux 2023]?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing, linux-networking, systemd

I'm trying to find the cause of an instance outage, which seems to be from a scheduled systemd `refresh-policy-routes` service, followed by a `404 Error` call to `EC2RoleProvider`. After the error, all network connectivity on the instance failed (including ssh). What does `refresh-policy-routes` do?

```
Starting refresh-policy-routes@ens5.service - Refresh policy routes for ens5...
Starting sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool...
sysstat-collect.service: Deactivated successfully.
Finished sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool.

SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=<sess> ses=<sess> subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 
msg='unit=sysstat-collect comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=<sess> ses=<sess> subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 
msg='unit=sysstat-collect comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'

Starting configuration for ens5
/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online ens5

[get_meta] Querying IMDS for mac
Got IMDSv2 token from http://169.254.169.254/latest
Using existing cfgfile /run/systemd/network/70-ens5.network
[get_meta] Querying IMDS for network/interfaces/macs/<mac-addr>/local-ipv4s
Got IMDSv2 token from http://169.254.169.254/latest
[get_meta] Querying IMDS for network/interfaces/macs/<mac-addr>/ipv4-prefix
Got IMDSv2 token from http://169.254.169.254/latest
[get_meta] Querying IMDS for network/interfaces/macs/<mac-addr>/local-ipv4s
Got IMDSv2 token from http://169.254.169.254/latest

Called trap
No networkd reload needed

refresh-policy-routes@ens5.service: Deactivated successfully.
Finished refresh-policy-routes@ens5.service - Refresh policy routes for ens5.

SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=<sess> ses=<sess> subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 
msg='unit=refresh-policy-routes@ens5 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=<sess> ses=<sess> subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 
msg='unit=refresh-policy-routes@ens5 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'

2024-02-11 08:30:46 WARN EC2RoleProvider Failed to connect
 to Systems Manager with instance profile role credentials. 
 Err: retrieved credentials failed to report to ssm. Error: EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found
 caused by: EC2MetadataError: failed to make EC2Metadata request
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
     <head>
      <title>404 - Not Found</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
     </body>
    </html>
        status code: 404, request id:
```

Comment: Yes, this is a pain. I was forced to increase the timeout and interval parameters on the load balancing target groups to prevent autoscaling from kicking in.

Comment: @josh-hibschman -- are you still seeing this? What did you do to solve? I am going crazy. This is the only error I can find that relates to my AWS instance stopping responding to requests. It's periodic. Comes back on its own.

Comment: @DanM - were you having your instances stop responding to traffic periodically when this log message was running?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be removed (or fixed) the behavior at `cleanup` and `stop` of `setup-policy-routes.sh`.
I hope this update helps you.

https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-ec2-net-utils/pull/107

---

### (too long) postscript

> What does refresh-policy-routes do?

#### `refresh-policy-routes@<iface>.service`

`refresh-policy-routes@<iface>.service` invokes a script `setup-policy-routes` twice  (at least in `aws-ec2-net-utils v2.4.1`).
At first, the script is invoked with the argument `start`, then with `cleanup`.

https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-ec2-net-utils/blob/b721f411c2e7ca00534cfa0b03089976c0a434ac/systemd/system/refresh-policy-routes%40.service#L10-L11

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setup-policy-routes %i start
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/setup-policy-routes %i cleanup
```

With the argument `start`, it executes `systemd-networkd-wait-online`.
With the argument `cleanup`, it removes a lock file if it remains.
But I have not understand the behavior precisely yet.

https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-ec2-net-utils/blob/b721f411c2e7ca00534cfa0b03089976c0a434ac/bin/setup-policy-routes.sh#L41-L63

```shell
    info "Starting configuration for $iface"
    debug /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online -i "$iface"
    /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online -i "$iface"
```

```shell
        info "WARNING: Cleaning up leaked lock ${lockdir}/${iface}"
        rm -f "${lockdir}/${iface}"
```

By the way, the service unit itself has no `[Install]` section in its unit file.

https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-ec2-net-utils/blob/v2.4.1/systemd/system/refresh-policy-routes%40.service

So, it needs to be activated by other way. Here, `timer` type unit is used for.

#### `refresh-policy-routes@<iface>.timer`

When an interface is attached (or some event like it happens), an instantiated service unit `policy-routes@<iface>.service` which belongs to the interface is activated via `udev`.

`policy-routes@<iface>.service` also invokes `setup-policy-routes` twice, as same as `refresh-policy-routes@<iface>.service` does.

https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-ec2-net-utils/blob/b721f411c2e7ca00534cfa0b03089976c0a434ac/systemd/system/policy-routes%40.service#L14-L15

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setup-policy-routes %i start
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/setup-policy-routes %i cleanup
```

At the same time, `udev` enables `refresh-policy-routes@<iface>.timer` too.

But the timer waits 30 seconds to activate `refresh-policy-routes@<iface>.service` at first time.
And then the timer activates the service repeatedly every one or two minutes (as far as I saw in my environment).

https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-ec2-net-utils/blob/5ba0509505f60dfaa2edb3da6bca10228b17d041/systemd/system/refresh-policy-routes%40.timer#L1-L4

```
[Timer]
OnActiveSec=30
OnUnitInactiveSec=60
RandomizedDelaySec=5
```

#### summary

`setup-policy-routes.sh` is called many times by several triggers.
It is unclear what goes on (and what should be) at each phases.
This would make conflicts with other network-depended services or components.

I think some `After=` or `Before=` options or like them will be required (in unit files of `systemd`) to resolve such situations.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a custom AWS service
https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-ec2-net-utils/blob/main/systemd/system/refresh-policy-routes%40.service